# Join it / Join them

Tags: grammar

Can you explain me please when we should use "it" or "them" with the word company in the example below. 
As I understand company is "it", so we use **join it**? Or should we use **join them**?

*Our main partner is XXX (company) in the Netherlands. If you join **them/it**, we will offer you the different products to sell.*

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `join` isn't the best choice here. If you use it, use `join us`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both 'it' and 'them' can be used to refer to a company.

'It' in this case is referring to the company as an inanimate object, which it is. 'Them' can also be used because a company is a collection of people working there.

So it all comes down to perspective I suppose. 'It' may also seem to be slightly negative and seem colder than if you can 'them'. 'Them' can be seen as a warmer word choice that can make people 'feel better'.